# element type 'List<widget>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to output title (string) and list of items (widgets), but it is showing two errors.
one is

> element type 'List' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'** and second **the argument type "gridview" can't be assigned to the parameter type "iterable".

```
    List<Widget> categoriesWidgets;

    String categoryCaption,
    final List<Widget> result = <Widget>[];
```

```
    final Padding categoryTitleWidget = Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
    child: Text(categoryCaption));

    final GridView results = GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: <Widget>[result]
    );

    categoriesWidgets.add(categoryTitleWidget);
    categoriesWidgets.addAll(results);

    }
```

[image: errors]

Comment: the first one should be `children: results`  not `children : <Widget>[result]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create `array of list of Widget`. But the expected is `list of widget`.

Change

```
 children: <Widget>[result]
```

to

```
 children: result
```

---

**Edit:** *"grid view can't be assigned to parameter type iterable"*

Change the following code to:

```
categoriesWidgets.addAll([results]); // add results within []
```

Answer (score 1):

The `results` is a single widget `GridView`, it should use `add` instead of `addAll`.

```dart
  final GridView results = GridView.count(crossAxisCount: 2,children: result);
  categoriesWidgets.add(categoryTitleWidget);
  categoriesWidgets.add(results);
```